# Python Json fetch key Value

Tags: python, json

my response content is

```
{"VoucherQuantityResult":[{"ErrorCode":"E057","ErrorMessage":"IP not registered","Message":"IP not registered","QuantityResponse":[],"ResultType":"FAILED"}]}
```

responseDetails = response.json() results

```
{u'VoucherQuantityResult': [{u'ErrorCode': u'E057', u'ResultType': u'FAILED', u'Message': u'IP not registered', u'ErrorMessage': u'IP not registered', u'QuantityResponse': []}]}
```

then if I call, `errorCode = responseDetails['ErrorCode']['ResultType']`

there is error `KeyError: 'ErrorCode'`

I have even used the dumps function, `json.dumps(response.json())`

then the error is,

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Can some one suggest me how to fetch the keys and values without unicode?

Note: if I use python3 then I dont see any unicode character. still the issue

```
errorCode = responseDetails['ErrorCode']['value']
KeyError: 'ErrorCode'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see, your response is a list not a dict which contains dict as its items.

So you can access it like this;

```
errorCode = responseDetails[0]['ErrorCode']['ResultType']
```

OR

If this is your whole result;

```
{u'VoucherQuantityResult': [{u'ErrorCode': u'E057', u'ResultType': u'FAILED', u'Message': u'IP not registered', u'ErrorMessage': u'IP not registered', u'QuantityResponse': []}]}
```

Then use this;

```
responseDetails['VoucherQuantityResult'][0]['ErrorCode']['ResultType']
```

Comment: In short, you are not parsing the list but directly trying to jump to the dict

Comment: ok one more thing, if I use latest version of python (python3) then I am not getting the unicode character in Json. But still the issue of Key Error. Let me add this to question.

Comment: responseDetails = json.loads(response.content)
        print(responseDetails)
        errorCode = responseDetails['ErrorCode'] @irfan. I am parsing it

Comment: yes now I understood the issue, marking your response as answer. Thank you

Comment: Good to see that you got the answer. BTW unicode in json got removed in latest versions of python (python 3).

Comment: BTW did you by mistake edited my answer ??

Comment: yes I am not able to remove the edit. I am sorry.

Comment: That is ok... I just rejected that.